# is it okay to export a require() from another file like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file which uses another and expands its functionality (similar to inheritance pattern) similar to this :

*parent file*

```
module.exports.a = () => {}
module.exports.b = () => {}
```

*child file*

```
const parent = require("../parent")

module.exports.a = () => { parent.a() }
module.exports.b = () => { parent.b() }
module.exports.c = () => {}
```

I want to export the parent file functions inside the child file so when used outside it would look just like there is one file.
I tried this and it seems to work :

*child file*

```
const parent = require("../parent")
module.exports = {...module.exports, ...parent }
```

I was wondering if it is ok and safe to do this, and if it is, if there's a better/cleaner way ?

Comment: `I tried this and it seems to work` - then you're done (edit: for now).

Comment: it is safe.. to turn the 2 liner into a 1 liner.. you can even do this.. `module.exports={...module.exports, ...(require('../parent'))}`

Comment: @Adam - That's a very dangerous assumption to make, in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not re-assign `module.exports` if not necessary. Since you apparently want to keep its previous properties anyway, I'd recommend to rather do

```
const parent = require("../parent")
Object.assign(module.exports, parent)
```

This it totally fine and will work. A longer, but more explicit version (that might be deemed cleaner by some) would be

```
const parent = require("../parent")

module.exports.a = parent.a
module.exports.b = parent.b
module.exports.c = () => {}
```